# Digital Signature Softaware installation error

Tags: software-installation

[image]

On Ubuntu 20.04 when I am trying to install my digital signature software gets an  error as seen in the  image.

I tried earlier with wrong software.

[image]

Comment: What is this software? It looks suspicious to me "ubantu". Does it support 20.04. Try to install it with `sudo apt install ./Prox...`

Comment: 1) Please don't post screenshots of text. 2) I never meant running `sudo apt install` without the file specified. 3) Now I suggest running `sudo apt install -f` to fix the existing issues.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am getting this error while running sudo apt install -f. installed nicdsign package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nicdsign
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Run `sudo apt purge nicdsign`

Comment: @Pilot6 This software is developed and maintained by one of the govt departments in India (Kerala)
@LintoK.Kuriakose I faced the same problem yesterday. My understanding is the command
`chown: cannot access '/home//Desktop/NICDSign.desktop': No such file or directory`
Does not contain the username after /home/ causing the error.

You can try sending a mail to info@spark.gov.in or calling up the department and discussing the issue with them